# SQL Table schema

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following suggested table schema:

| client_type | last_phone_digits | items |
| --- | --- | --- |
| new | 00-49 | 1, 2, 3, 4 |
| new | 50-99 | 1, 2, 3, 4 |
| old | 00-49 | 5, 6, 7, 8 |
| old | 50-99 | 5, 6, 7, 8 |

At the moment there is an existing table without `last_phone_digits table` column and i need to embed this new column. The problem is my suggested variant did not satisfy the client, my variant:

| client_type | last_phone_digits | items |
| --- | --- | --- |
| new | 00 | 1, 2, 3, 4 |
| new | 01 | 1, 2, 3, 4 |
| new | 02 | 1, 2, 3, 4 |
| new | 03 | 1, 2, 3, 4 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| new | 99 | 1, 2, 3, 4 |

where client_type: enum, last_phone_digits: varchar, items: array
My point was to be able to tie `client_type` and `last_phone_digits` as a PRIMARY KEY, and fill this table with the following function:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fill_product_collection(
            from_val integer,
            to_val integer,
            prod_type product_type,
            product_items varchar[50]
        ) returns void as $$
            DECLARE
                val varchar;
            BEGIN
                FOR i IN from_val..to_val LOOP
                    val = CASE
                            WHEN i < 10 THEN '0' || i::varchar
                            ELSE i::varchar
                        END;
                    INSERT INTO product_collection(product_type, phone_digits, items) VALUES
                        (prod_type, val, product_items)
                    ON CONFLICT(product_type, phone_digits) DO UPDATE SET items=product_items;
                END LOOP;
            END
        $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

What do you think, is there some better option for this column, maybe change
`last_phone_digits` type to array and store whole digit combination on it? I don't know is it good option, because there will be problem with primary key of two columns `client_type` and `last_phone_digits`

Comment: You should avoid storing CSV data like this.  Consider redesigning the whole table.

Comment: Please give an example of how the table should look like

Comment: Just store one phone number and one item per row/record.  The output you want to see should be precisely just that - output from some query, but not your actual data model.

Comment: @ash . . . What do I think?  That is asking for an *opinion*.  You have not described the domain, why you are storing multiple values in a single column, or what the purpose of the table is.  You are really just asking for an opinion and you already have one from your client.